# Slow down transition with CSS

Tags: html, css

can someone tell me which tag I should use to configure the speed of my transition in css?

```
 #test2{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}
 #test2:hover{
  width: 400px;
  background: blue;
}
```

my code is like this

Answer (score 0):

You would need `transition-duration` to control the transition speed.

Or use this shorthand to set them in one go:

```css
transiton: all 1s;
```

```css
#test2{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  
  /* which properties should apply transitions */
  transition-property: background, width;
  
  /* how long does the transition take */
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

 #test2:hover{
  width: 400px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="test2">test 2</div>
```